# Nodejs api or module to gather azure Disk data for both managed and unmanaged disks(both data and os disks)

Tags: node.js, azure

Existing api's for data collection in Azure is minimal. One api call for gathering disk data only lists the different properties for managed OsDisks and not unmanaged ones.Also there is no api call for gathering details for Data Disks. I need to write nodejs code that gathers and collects various properties of both managed and unmanaged OsDisks and DataDisks respectively.

Tried using api calls for storage accounts to specifically filter data disks but the response doesnt give anything for unmanaged OsDisks and Datadisks.

I also tried gathering data for blobs but the api call for blobs gives back responses in xml format. I would like to gather blob data in json format and would also like to know if there is any api call for blobs that gives a response in json.  If no json response is given I would like to know a way on how to parse xml data for particular data and store them as a json.

```
Promise1 = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
 unirest.get('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/' + subscriptionId + '/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks?api-version=2018-06-01')
        .header('Authorization', token)
        .end(function (responseDisks){
            resolve(responseDisks)
            reject(err)
      })
    })
    Promise1.then(function(responseDisks){  
        var diskName = []
        var diskLocation = []
        var disk_sku_name = []
        var disk_sku_tier = []
        var disk_created_time = []
        var disk_osType = []
        var disk_creationData_option = []
        var disk_creationData_imageReference = []
        var disk_SizeGB = []
```

So this code gathers and collects data only for managed Os Disks. The https get request is an Azure Api call that supposedly gives a response containing all the data for all disks in an Azure Subscription but not data for unmanaged OsDisks and nothing for Data Disks.